# 2 extra zeros money field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I use `money-rails` gem in my rails application.
I have model `Transaction`.

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  monetize :amount_money, as: :amount, with_model_currency: :currency, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}
end
```

And form for adding new transaction.

```
= simple_form_for [:post_manager, @transaction] do |f|
  = f.label t('activerecord.attributes.transaction.amount')
  = f.input :amount, class: 'form-control'

  = f.submit t('views.transactions.submit.create'), class: 'btn btn-md btn-success'
```

In my controller action:

```
def create
  @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
  @transaction.save

  respond_with(@transaction, location: post_manager_transactions_path)
end
```

In my money initializer:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
   config.register_currency = {
    priority: 1,
    iso_code: 'BYR',
    name: 'Belarusian Ruble',
    symbol: 'Br',
    disambiguate_symbol: 'BYR',
    subunit_to_unit: 1,
    symbol_first: false,
    decimal_mark: '.',
    thousands_separator: ' ',
    iso_numeric: '974',
    smallest_denomination: 100
   }
end
```

When I try to add new transaction:

In my controller action:

```
[1] pry(#<PostManager::TransactionsController>)> @transaction
=> #<Transaction:0x000001018ebfa0 id: nil, kind: "withdraw", amount_money: 12300, note:        "vf", approved: nil, wallet_id: 1, category_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(#<PostManager::TransactionsController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"hAHFdamHK7CI41zXiHUCSb+RUg+57JR9sZTIhi2frcLEQELakQuOvhs8xaWMwK32XbxTsTfplCQJA7XigsueLQ==",
"transaction"=>{"kind"=>"withdraw", "category_id"=>"1", "amount"=>"123", "note"=>"vf"},
"commit"=>"Создать операцию",
"controller"=>"post_manager/transactions",
"action"=>"create"}
```

So. In my params :amount is 123, but in my new transaction :amount is 12300, so i have 2 extra zeros in my amount money field.

And I really don't know how to fix it. Maybe someone have had such problem before?

Comment: I belive that two zeroes are kopejki =)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, no, it's not kopejki :)

Comment: The money gem does it's calculations in cent. They claim to have less round issues by this strategy. Так что это все таки копейки :) `Represents monetary values as integers, in cents. This avoids floating point rounding errors`

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour of the `money-rails` gem. It will save the currency amount in it's lowest denomination in order to prevent rounding errors.

Since you have not specified the currency of the amount you're entering, it defaults to `USD` and converts it to cents, which is why you're seeing that result:

`$123 * 100 = 12300`

The gem is smart enough to convert currency amounts into their lowest denomination. However, it needs to know the currency it is working with, since not all currencies behave the same.

The way you approach this is dependent on your application logic. However, as a test you could add the following hidden field to your form that would yield the result you expect.

`= f.input :amount_currency, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "BYR" }`

L